# Is it possible to overwrite an object after being passed?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

See the following example:

```js
var foo = { bar : 0 };

function modify(obj)
{
    obj = {};
}

modify(foo);

console.log(foo);
```

My first object in the global scope remains unchanged. Because the function did not replace the object but a copy of the reference.

So my question is simple. Does anyone know of a work-around way, or are there ECMAScript features in currently development or have there been attempts to make this possible at all?

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't passing foo as argument of your function. By the way, you don't want to overwrite stuff in this way. Read about stateless functions

Comment: You're defining `modify` with one parameter, but calling it with none. Did you mean to call it with `foo`?

Comment: No, that's not the way JS works now or will ever.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Changed it

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the binding of the variable that you were called with. But since you receive a reference to the same object, you can modify the object itself. So you can remove all the properties:

```js
function modify(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    delete obj[k];
  });
}

var foo = { a: 3 };
console.log(foo);
modify(foo);
console.log(foo);
```